# What does selecting the largest eigenvalues and eigenvectors in the covariance matrix mean in data analysis?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, pca, data-analysis

Suppose there is a matrix `B`, where its size is a `500*1000 double`(Here, `500` represents the number of observations and `1000` represents the number of features).

`sigma` is the covariance matrix of `B`, and `D` is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal elements are the eigenvalues of `sigma`. Assume `A` is the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix `sigma`.

I have the following questions:

1. I need to select the first `k = 800` eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalues with the largest magnitude to rank the selected features. The final matrix named `Aq`. How can I do this in MATLAB?
2. What is the meaning of these selected eigenvectors?
3. It seems the size of the final matrix `Aq` is `1000*800 double` once I calculate `Aq`. The time points/observation information of `500` has disappeared. For the final matrix `Aq`, what does the value `1000` in matrix `Aq` represent now? Also, what does the value `800` in matrix `Aq` represent now?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm assuming you determined the eigenvectors from the [`eig`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html) function.  What I would recommend to you in the future is to use the [`eigs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eigs.html) function.  This not only computes the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for you, but it will compute the `k` **largest** eigenvalues with their associated eigenvectors for you.  This may save computational overhead where you don't have to compute all of the eigenvalues and associated eigenvectors of your matrix as you only want a subset.  You simply supply the covariance matrix of your data to `eigs` and it returns the `k` largest eigenvalues and eigenvectors for you.

---

Now, back to your problem, what you are describing is ultimately [Principal Component Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis).  The mechanics behind this would be to compute the covariance matrix of your data and find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the computed result.  It has been known that doing it this way is not recommended due to numerical instability with computing the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for large matrices.  The most canonical way to do this now is via [Singular Value Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition).  Concretely, the columns of the `V` matrix give you the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix, or the principal components, and the associated eigenvalues are the square root of the singular values produced in the diagonals of the matrix `S`.

See this informative post on Cross Validated as to why this is preferred:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79043/why-pca-of-data-by-means-of-svd-of-the-data

I'll throw in another link as well that talks about the theory behind why the Singular Value Decomposition is used in Principal Component Analysis:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134282/relationship-between-svd-and-pca-how-to-use-svd-to-perform-pca

---

Now let's answer your question one at a time.

## Question #1

MATLAB generates the eigenvalues and the corresponding ordering of the eigenvectors in such a way where they are **unsorted**.  If you wish to select out the largest `k` eigenvalues and associated eigenvectors given the output of `eig` (800 in your example), you'll need to **sort** the eigenvalues in descending order, then rearrange the columns of the eigenvector matrix produced from `eig` then select out the first `k` values.

I should also note that using `eigs` will not guarantee sorted order, so you will have to explicitly sort these too when it comes down to it.

In MATLAB, doing what we described above would look something like this:

```
sigma = cov(B);
[A,D] = eig(sigma);
vals = diag(D);
[~,ind] = sort(abs(vals), 'descend');
Asort = A(:,ind);
```

It's a good thing to note that you do the sorting **on the absolute value of the eigenvalues** because scaled eigenvalues are also eigenvalues themselves.  These scales also include negatives.  This means that if we had a component whose eigenvalue was, say -10000, this is a very good indication that this component has some significant meaning to your data, and if we sorted purely on the numbers themselves, this gets placed near the lower ranks.

The first line of code finds the covariance matrix of `B`, even though you said it's already stored in `sigma`, but let's make this reproducible.  Next, we find the eigenvalues of your covariance matrix and the associated eigenvectors.  Take note that each column of the eigenvector matrix `A` represents one eigenvector.  Specifically, the i<sup>th</sup> column / eigenvector of `A` corresponds to the i<sup>th</sup> eigenvalue seen in `D`.

However, the eigenvalues are in a diagonal matrix, so we extract out the diagonals with the [`diag`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diag.html) command, sort them and figure out their ordering, then rearrange `A` to respect this ordering.  I use the second output of `sort` because it tells you the position of where each value in the unsorted result would appear in the sorted result.  This is the ordering we need to rearrange the columns of the eigenvector matrix `A`.  It's imperative that you choose `'descend'` as the flag so that the largest eigenvalue and associated eigenvector appear first, just like we talked about before.

You can then pluck out the first `k` largest vectors and values via:

```
k = 800;
Aq = Asort(:,1:k);
```

## Question #2

It's a well known fact that the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix are equal to the principal components.  Concretely, the first principal component (i.e. the largest eigenvector and associated largest eigenvalue) gives you the direction of the **maximum variability** in your data.  Each principal component after that gives you variability of a decreasing nature.  It's also good to note that each principal component is **orthogonal** to each other.

Here's a good example from Wikipedia for two dimensional data:

[image]

I pulled the above image from the Wikipedia article on Principal Component Analysis, which I linked you to above. This is a scatter plot of samples that are distributed according to a bivariate Gaussian distribution centred at `(1,3)` with a standard deviation of 3 in roughly the `(0.878, 0.478)` direction and of 1 in the orthogonal direction.  The component with a standard deviation of 3 is the first principal component while the one that is orthogonal is the second component.  The vectors shown are the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix scaled by the square root of the corresponding eigenvalue, and shifted so their tails are at the mean.

Now let's get back to your question.  The reason why we take a look at the `k` largest eigenvalues is a way of performing [dimensionality reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction).  Essentially, you would be performing a data compression where you would take your higher dimensional data and project them onto a lower dimensional space.  The more principal components you include in your projection, the more it will resemble the original data.  It actually begins to taper off at a certain point, but the first few principal components allow you to faithfully reconstruct your data for the most part.

A great visual example of performing PCA (or SVD rather) and data reconstruction is found by this great Quora post I stumbled upon in the past.

http://qr.ae/RAEU8a

## Question #3

You would use this matrix to reproject your higher dimensional data onto a lower dimensional space.  The number of rows being 1000 is still there, which means that there were originally 1000 features in your dataset.  The 800 is what the reduced dimensionality of your data would be.  Consider this matrix as a transformation from the original dimensionality of a feature (1000) down to its reduced dimensionality (800).

You would then use this matrix in conjunction with **reconstructing** what the original data was.  Concretely, this would give you an approximation of what the original data looked like with the least amount of error.  In this case, you don't need to use all of the principal components (i.e. just the `k` largest vectors) and you can create an approximation of your data with less information than what you had before.

How you reconstruct your data is very simple. Let's talk about the forward and reverse operations first with the full data.  The forward operation is to take your original data and reproject it but instead of the lower dimensionality, we will use **all** of the components.  You first need to have your original data but mean subtracted:

```
Bm = bsxfun(@minus, B, mean(B,1));
```

`Bm` will produce a matrix where each feature of every sample is mean subtracted. [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) allows the subtraction of two matrices in unequal dimension provided that you can **broadcast** the dimensions so that they can both match up.  Specifically, what will happen in this case is that the mean of each column / feature of `B` will be computed and a temporary replicated matrix will be produced that is as large as `B`.  When you subtract your original data with this replicated matrix, the effect will subtract every data point with their respective feature means, thus decentralizing your data so that the mean of each feature is 0.

Once you do this, the operation to project is simply:

```
Bproject = Bm*Asort;
```

The above operation is quite simple.  What you are doing is expressing each sample's feature as a linear combination of principal components.  For example, given the first sample or first row of the decentralized data, the first sample's feature in the projected domain is a dot product of the row vector that pertains to the entire sample and the first principal component which is a column vector..  The first sample's second feature in the projected domain is a weighted sum of the entire sample and the second component.  You would repeat this for all samples and all principal components.  In effect, you are reprojecting the data so that it is with respect to the principal components - which are orthogonal basis vectors that transform your data from one representation to another.

A better description of what I just talked about can be found here.  Look at Amro's answer:

[Matlab Principal Component Analysis (eigenvalues order)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991343/matlab-principal-component-analysis-eigenvalues-order)

Now to go backwards, you simply do the inverse operation, but a special property with the eigenvector matrix is that if you transpose this, you get the inverse.  To get the original data back, you undo the operation above and add the means back to the problem:

```
out = bsxfun(@plus, Bproject*Asort.', mean(B, 1));
```

You want to get the original data back, so you're solving for `Bm` with respect to the previous operation that I did.  However, the inverse of `Asort` is just the transpose here.  What's happening after you perform this operation is that you are getting the original data back, but the data is still decentralized.  To get the original data back, you must add the means of each feature back into the data matrix to get the final result.  That's why we're using another `bsxfun` call here so that you can do this for each sample's feature values.

You should be able to go back and forth from the original domain and projected domain with the above two lines of code.  Now where the dimensionality reduction (or the approximation of the original data) comes into play is the reverse operation.  What you need to do first is project the data onto the bases of the principal components (i.e. the forward operation), but now to go back to the original domain where we are trying to reconstruct the data with a reduced number of principal components, you simply replace `Asort` in the above code with `Aq` and also reduce the amount of features you're using in `Bproject`.  Concretely:

```
out = bsxfun(@plus, Bproject(:,1:k)*Aq.', mean(B, 1));
```

Doing `Bproject(:,1:k)` selects out the `k` features in the projected domain of your data, corresponding to the `k` largest eigenvectors.  Interestingly, if you just want the representation of the data with regards to a reduced dimensionality, you can just use `Bproject(:,1:k)` and that'll be enough.  However, if you want to go forward and compute an approximation of the original data, we need to compute the reverse step.  The above code is simply what we had before with the full dimensionality of your data, but we use `Aq` as well as selecting out the `k` features in `Bproject`.  This will give you the original data that is represented by the `k` largest eigenvectors / eigenvalues in your matrix.

---

If you'd like to see an awesome example, I'll mimic the Quora post that I linked to you but using another image.  Consider doing this with a grayscale image where each row is a "sample" and each column is a feature.  Let's take the cameraman image that's part of the image processing toolbox:

```
im = imread('camerman.tif');
imshow(im); %// Using the image processing toolbox
```

We get this image:

[image]

This is a 256 x 256 image, which means that we have 256 data points and each point has 256 features.  What I'm going to do is convert the image to `double` for precision in computing the covariance matrix.  Now what I'm going to do is repeat the above code, but incrementally increasing `k` at each go from 3, 11, 15, 25, 45, 65 and 125.  Therefore, for each `k`, we are introducing more principal components and we should slowly start to get a reconstruction of our data.

Here's some runnable code that illustrates my point:

```
%%%%%%%// Pre-processing stage
clear all;
close all;

%// Read in image - make sure we cast to double
B = double(imread('cameraman.tif'));

%// Calculate covariance matrix
sigma = cov(B);

%// Find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the covariance matrix
[A,D] = eig(sigma);
vals = diag(D);

%// Sort their eigenvalues
[~,ind] = sort(abs(vals), 'descend');

%// Rearrange eigenvectors
Asort = A(:,ind);

%// Find mean subtracted data
Bm = bsxfun(@minus, B, mean(B,1));

%// Reproject data onto principal components
Bproject = Bm*Asort;

%%%%%%%// Begin reconstruction logic
figure;
counter = 1;

for k = [3 11 15 25 45 65 125 155]
    %// Extract out highest k eigenvectors
    Aq = Asort(:,1:k);

    %// Project back onto original domain
    out = bsxfun(@plus, Bproject(:,1:k)*Aq.', mean(B, 1));

    %// Place projection onto right slot and show the image
    subplot(4, 2, counter);
    counter = counter + 1;
    imshow(out,[]);
    title(['k = ' num2str(k)]);
end
```

As you can see, the majority of the code is the same from what we have seen.  What's different is that I loop over all values of `k`, project back onto the original space (i.e. computing the approximation) with the `k` highest eigenvectors, then show the image.

We get this nice figure:

[image]

As you can see, starting with `k=3` doesn't really do us any favours... we can see some general structure, but it wouldn't hurt to add more in.  As we start increasing the number of components, we start to get a clearer picture of what the original data looks like.  At `k=25`, we actually can see what the cameraman looks like perfectly, and we don't need components 26 and beyond to see what's happening.  This is what I was talking about with regards to data compression where you don't need to work on all of the principal components to get a clear picture of what's going on.

---

I'd like to end this note by referring you to Chris Taylor's wonderful exposition on the topic of Principal Components Analysis, with code, graphs and a great explanation to boot!  This is where I got started on PCA, but the Quora post is what solidified my knowledge.

[Matlab - PCA analysis and reconstruction of multi dimensional data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688312/matlab-pca-analysis-and-reconstruction-of-multi-dimensional-data)

Comment: @Shawn As stated in your post, yes.  It's the covariance matrix of `B`.

Comment: after executing [A,D] = eig(sigma); The size of A is 1000*6 double, shouldn't it be 1000*1000 double?

Comment: should I do like this => first: [rb, cb] = size(B); then: [A, D] = eig(sigma, cb) .

Comment: Is there any intuition behind eigenvectors and eigenvalues of data matrix itself (not covariance of it)?

Comment: @Shawn - `[A,D] = eig(cov(B));`

Comment: @Olologin - I've honestly never used eigenvectors and eigenvalues beyond the covariance matrix.  However, from what I know of them, eigenvectors and eigenvalues have a result such that a matrix multiplication between a matrix and a vector is equal to taking the same vector and scaling it by a certain amount.  This in a geometrical sense has the appearance of the vectors simply being scaled if you pulled them in a direction parallel to the eigenvectors.  Check this nice animated GIF on Wikipedia for more details: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/06/Eigenvectors.gif

Comment: @rayryeng, you said:"Remember that when you computed the covariance matrix, you needed to mean subtract each feature in your matrix, and so let's call this mean subtracted matrix RowDataAdjust".  I do not understand this. I thought covariance matrix  = cov(B). How to realize what you said?

Comment: @Shawn - I've added in a concrete example and working code.  Have a look and let me know what you think.

Comment: @Olologin - I've added in a concrete reproducible example.  Let me know what you think!

Comment: @rayryeng, I just go out. I will read your post carefully. Really thank you!

Comment: Great job! Also, the Qoura post is quite nice. Specially because it contains a picture of Feynman :-D

Comment: @rayryeng, I already vote you! But I will read it very carefully!!! Really appreciate!

Comment: @LuisMendo - Yes that was a very nice post :) that's why I linked to it, and that's how I got the idea of showing the reconstruction with images.  It's not as epic as Dr. Feynman, but still a good representation of what's going on :)

Comment: @Shawn - Thank you :)  BTW, I've updated my post to include more details.  This should hopefully answer all of your questions.

Comment: @rayryeng， Can you write another way to do PCA by using SVD, instead of covariance of matrix B ?

Comment: @Shawn - Don't think I need to.  There's an SVD link I sent you that talks about this at the top: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134282/relationship-between-svd-and-pca-how-to-use-svd-to-perform-pca - Read point #9 specifically.