# Should the input vectors for SVD (in Matlab) be arranged by rows or column?

Tags: matlab, svd, dimensionality-reduction

I have a matrix of data A with dimension m-by-n. Where m is the number of data vectors and n is the dimension if each data vector (so they are arranged by rows).

If I do

```
[U,S,V] = svds(A, k);
```

the U matrix will be m-by-k, but I was expecting a n-by-k matrix (to be used to project any 1-by-n original vector to a 1-by-k one).
What I am doing wrong? Should I arrange data by column? (i.e., use A' instead of A)

Comment: Nothing is wrong.  That's what the SVD function returns.  Documentation says: `[U,S,V] = svds(A,...) computes the singular vectors as well. If A is M-by-N and K singular values are computed, then U is M-by-K with orthonormal columns, S is K-by-K diagonal, and V is N-by-K with orthonormal columns.`... so the function is doing what it's supposed to do.  Please provide more context into your problem. The function is doing what it's supposed to be doing.

Comment: My aim dimensionality reduction, therefore is to take the first k singular vectors to transform my 1-by-n vectors to a reduced version of 1-by-k.

If U has dimension m-by-k (i.e., one dimension is related to the number of data I have, not their dimension), how can I use it to transform an arbitrary 1-by-n vector to a 1-by-k ?

Comment: You simply have to multiply `U` by `S`.  `B = U * S` gives you the dimensionality reduced set where each row of `B` produces the dimensionality reduced representation of each example you provided in `A`: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/107533/how-to-use-svd-for-dimensionality-reduction-to-reduce-the-number-of-columns-fea

Comment: And what is the projection matrix for any arbitrary new 1-by-n vector?

Comment: That would be the columns of `V`.  Given that your data is standardized, `U * S = X * V` where `X` is the mean subtracted dataset with each feature (i.e. `X = bsxfun(@minus, A, mean(A, 1));`). Therefore, when you apply the `svd` on `X`, the projection matrix to reduce your dimensionality down to `k` is the first `k` columns of `V`. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134282/relationship-between-svd-and-pca-how-to-use-svd-to-perform-pca.  Take any vector from your dataset in `X` or any row that is `1 x n` and multiply with the matrix `V` of size `n x k` to reduce your data down to `1 x k`.

Comment: The link you provided says:  "To reduce the dimensionality of the data from p to k<p, select the first k columns of U, and the k×k upper-left part of S. Their product Uk X Sk is the required n×k matrix containing first k PCs." but you say to take the first k columns of V. What is the right one?

Comment: They are both correct.  `U * S = X * V` given that the data is standardized.  By taking the first `k` columns of `U * S` or the first `k` columns of `V` and multiplying by `X`, the result is the same.  Note that `X = U * S * V^{T}` but because `V` (or `U`) is orthonormal, `V^{-1} = V^{T}` and so we can move `V` to the left side of the equation, hence the relationship.  You can write a very small MATLAB script to test this: `A = rand(100,4); X = bsxfun(@minus, A, mean(A, 1)); [U,S,V] = svds(X, 2); B1 = U*S; B2 = X*V; e = norm(B1(:) - B2(:)) < 1e-10;`. `e` should be 1 denoting their equivalence.

Comment: Therefore to store the parameters to apply the projection to new data I should only save V (since i used svds V has exactly k columns) and the mean vector of A (needed to normalize the new data before projecting).*
Is it correct?

Comment: That is correct!  Make sure your data is mean subtracted then extract whichever vector you want and then use the first `k` columns of `V` to do the projection.  If you have **new** data, you **must** make sure you keep the means of each feature as you need these to subtract with the new data sample as that is what the `svd` used for reduction.  Therefore, given a new point, keep the mean feature vector and keep the first `k` columns of `V`.  This post I wrote a long time ago may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39706561/how-to-use-eigenvectors-obtained-through-pca-to-reproject-my-data/